# Capture image with MediaStreamSource

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera, windows-phone, media-library

Im using a MediaStreamSource to use the camera... everything works, except when I try to capture the image!

I think the problem is the object MediaStreamSource

```
public class CameraStreamSourceModel : MediaStreamSource
{
    private MemoryStream _cameraStream = null; // here I've the stream from camera

    ...

    public async void CapturePhoto()
    {
        // Save the image as a jpeg to the camera roll 
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();

        string filename = AppResources.ApplicationTitle + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
        Picture pic = library.SavePicture(filename, _cameraStream);  //Here I've the exception
    }
}
```

The exception is

> System.InvalidOperationException: An unexpected error has occurred.

I've enabled `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO`.

I am sure the code to save image works because i can save static stream in media library, but not stream from camera!

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a camera_capture_task

```
CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask;


public Transaction()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
            cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);
        }

void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {


            //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                pic.Source = bmp;
            pic_name = "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "" + DateTime.Now.Second+".jpeg";
            SaveToIsolatedStorage(e.ChosenPhoto, "" + pic_name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, im sorry I do not need a basic camera :(